# SQL query return a >= some_value and b is the maximum for given a

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with these attributes

```
a, b
1, 1
2, 1
3, 1
4, 1
3, 3
4, 3
5, 3
6, 3
```

And I want to have a query that returns the rows that have a >= some_value and b is the maximum for given a.
So the result I want for a >= 2 should be:

```
a, b
2, 1
3, 3
4, 3
5, 3
6, 3
```

I cannot find a way to make this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select a, max(b)
from t
where a >= 2
group by a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
SELECT A, MAX(B) FROM TABLE WHERE A >=foo 
GROUP BY A 
HAVING MAX(B)
```